# Is it possible to give dynamic names to HTML input buttons?

Tags: php, html, dynamic

Here is my current code:

```
<?php    
    for ( $i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++ ) {
?>

<form action="kill_threads.php" method="POST" >
     <label> 
          <?php echo "<br/><br/>Thread ".$i;?>
          <input type="submit" name = " <?php echo "thread".$i;} ?> " /> 
     </label>
     <input type="submit" name="test" />
</form>

<?php
     for ( $i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++ ) {
         $thread_name = "thread" . $i;
         if ( isset( $_POST[thread_name] ) ) echo "im a killed thread now";
     }
?>
```

My buttons are not working if i click on them, because i know im doing something wrong.Please help,thanks in advance.

Comment: Space in the Element name ?

Comment: Are your buttons even _submitting the form_? Besides, your code will issue a warning: `$_POST[thread_name]` <- unexpected constant, PHP will assume you meant `'thread_name'` (a string), but just add the quotes ffs.

Comment: no i dont get any messages about unexepted constant...and i added the quotes but the same...nothing happens..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make the following changes and it will work

```
<form action="kill_threads.php" method="POST" >
<?php 
  for ($i=1; $i<=9; $i++) { ?>
    <label> 
            <?php echo "<br/><br/>Thread ".$i;?>  
            <input type="submit" name="<?php echo  "thread".$i; ?>" /> 
    </label>
<?php
  } ?>
 <input type="submit" name="test" />
</form>

<?php
   for ($i=1; $i<=9; $i++) {
     $thread_name = "thread".$i;
     if ( isset($_POST[$thread_name] ) ) echo "im a killed thread now";
   } ?>
```

EDIT

The earlier code had the for loop ending brace in the this line

```
    <input type="submit" name="<?php echo  "thread".$i; } ?>" />
```

I have simply removed the ending brace } and put it after

```
   </label>
```

Comment: If you could highlight what you changed, it will help others as well. Cheers!!

Comment: could you please look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65422388/how-to-name-numerous-dynamic-input-fields-for-post-method-django)

Answer (score 0):

try this

it seems u r generating multiple forms

```
<form action="kill_threads.php" method="POST" >
<?php     
    for ( $i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++ ) 
    {
          echo "<lable>";
          echo "<br/><br/>Thread ".$i;
  ?>
          <input type="submit" name = " <?php echo "thread".$i; ?> " /> 
<?php
          echo "</lable>";
    }
     </label>
     <input type="submit" name="test" />
</form>

// php script
<?php
     for ( $i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++ ) {
         $thread_name = "thread" . $i;
         if ( isset( $_POST[thread_name] ) ) echo "im a killed thread now";
     }
?>
```