# how to name numerous dynamic input fields for post method - Django

Tags: html, post, django-views, django-templates, http-post

In my online shop, I fetch all of the products and services from two different apps and list them for the user to make his wishlist.

Each product or service is displayed in a bootstrap card that contains an input field for the count of products.

```
#views.py
def my_products(request):
    
    ip_sensor = Ip_sensor.objects.all().order_by('title')
    control_valves = ControlValves.objects.all().order_by('title')

    context = {
        'ip_sensor': ip_sensor,
        'control_valves': control_valves,        
    }
    return render(request, 'users/basket/my_products.html', context)
```

then in the template, they are being displayed in this way:

```
<form method="post" id="add_to_wishlist" data-url="{% url 'my_products' %}">
{% csrf_token %}

{% if ip_sensor %}
{% for item in ip_sensor %}

    <div class="card">

      <div class="card-body">

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-12">
            <p class="card-text text-center text-capitalize">{{ item.title }}</p>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="hidden" name="tag" value="{{ item.type }}">  <!-- what to put in name field of this line -->         
              <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{{ item.id }}">   <!-- what to put in name field of this line -->         
              <label for="count" class="control-label">count</label>     
              <input  type="text"    
                      id="count" 
                      name="count"             <!-- what to put in name field of this line -->         
                      placeholder="Count" 
                      class="form-control"
                      autofocus/> 
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}

</form>
```

**Question:**

**When I return the count of each product or service through a POST method back to my `views.py` to save to his wishlist, I don't know how to distinguish between the returned values??**

Since items are being displayed in a for loop and I want to save each of the selected items separately in a `WishListItem` object (model), I need to name each card's input fields separately but I don't know how to do it.

I can save each item in this way:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    owner = request.user

    count = request.POST.get('count')
    tag = request.POST.get('tag') 
    object_id = request.POST.get('item_id')
    
    wishlist = WishListItem(owner=owner,
                            content_type=class_types[tag],
                            object_id=object_id,
                            tag=tag,
                            count=count)
    wishlist.save()
    
    return redirect('my_products')
```

Answer (score 1):

When there are multiple inputs with same name, `request.POST` has list of all those input element values. So, you can get all item ids using `request.POST.getlist('item_id')` and it will return list containing all ids. In your html you can name all other inputs using `id` as part of the `name` attribute, like this:

```html
...
<input type="hidden" name="tag_{{ item.id }}" value="{{ item.type }}">  <!-- item id has become part of the input name -->         
<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{{ item.id }}">   <!-- all item ids will be accessed as list in view -->         
<label for="count" class="control-label">count</label>     
<input  type="text"    
                      id="count" 
                      name="count_{{ item.id }}" <!-- item id has become part of the input name -->         
                      placeholder="Count" 
                      class="form-control"
                      autofocus/>
...
```

And in your view you can access all values like this:

```py
...
for object_id in request.POST.getlist('item_id'): #this will contain a list with all item ids in it
    count = request.POST.get('count_%s'%object_id) #as html inputs are named with ids as part of name you can access them
    tag = request.POST.get('tag_%s'%object_id) #as html inputs are named with ids as part of name you can access them
    wishlist = WishListItem(owner=owner,
                    content_type=class_types[tag],
                    object_id=object_id,
                    tag=tag,
                    count=count)
    wishlist.save()
...
```

Comment: nice idea, but there is a problem, since the products are being loaded from multiple tables, they may have the same `id`s. then I get same `WishListItem` objects created after this for loop. another problem is that even if the values are `0`, a `WishListItem` will be created for them, I tried `if count != 0: wishlist = WishListItem(owner=owner...` but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer based on @datosula's answer.

since the product id may be repetitive because products are loaded from various tables, then a unique tag is required to distinguish returned values in `views.py`. I mixed up product's title and products type to achieve this:

```
<div class="form-group">

    <input type="hidden" name="title_type" value="{{ item.title }}{{ item.type }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id_{{ item.title }}{{ item.type }}" value="{{ item.id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="tag_{{ item.title }}{{ item.type }}" value="{{ item.type }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="title_{{ item.title }}{{ item.type }}" value="{{ item.title }}">
                                  
    <div class="text-center">
        <input  type="number" 
                id="count" 
                name="count_{{ item.title }}{{ item.type }}" 
                placeholder="count" 
                class="form-control"
                value="0"
                min="0"
                max="9999"
                autofocus/>
    </div>

</div>
```

in `views.py` I got the values and created the object like the following:

```
....
for item in request.POST.getlist('title_type'):
            object_id = request.POST.get('item_id_%s'%item)
            tag = request.POST.get('tag_%s'%item)
            print('\ntag: ', tag )
            print('\nclass_types[tag]: ', class_types[tag])
            count = request.POST.get('count_%s'%item)
            title = request.POST.get('title_%s'%item)
            if count != '0':  # only save those products that their count is not 0
                wishlist = WishListItem(owner=owner,
                                content_type=class_types[tag],
                                object_id=object_id,
                                tag=tag,
                                count=count,
                                title=title)
                wishlist.save()
....
```

wish it helps somebody